# Each results from drupal_view

Tags: views, theming

I need to create a select with the results of all elements of a particular content-type.

The results of all the elements of said content-type I get them like this:

```
{{drupal_view ('areas_practicas', 'areas_all')}}
```

But it generates preformatted results (with HTML in between) (or with the output of the development mode, with reference to the template that uses that sample)

- 1) Is it possible to return only one array of strings to be able to paint them in the select, without HTML or anything?
- 2) Is it possible to traverse the results of this block since twig?
  Something like

```
{% for area in drupal_view ('areas_practicas', 'areas_all') %}
    {{area.title}}
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:
first get a set of all needed nodes with a query, and then process the node to create your select

For all published articles of content type 'areas_practicas' for example:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition('type', 'areas_practicas');
$nids = $query->execute();
foreach ($nids as $node)
{   
    $n = node_load ((int)$node);
    // get title of node and process it
}
```

I hope this helps, Ruud